# Windows 7 use ethernet and wifi simultaneously

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I am on a shared ethernet network for internet and I wanted to be able to set up a plex media server using wifi at the same time. so essentially i'd be able to broadcast my media over wifi. would i be able to do this? it seems like windows 7 chooses one or the other. can i have them active at the same time.

Comment: Would both of these devices be on the same network? Because I know you can have simultaneous connections to different networks, but not sure about the same network with different traffic...

Comment: You can't use one wifi adapter to connect to 2 networks, but you can use 2 wifi adapters to connect the same windows computer to 2 networks.

Comment: nope these would be two different networks. the wired is the shared network with internet. the wifi is the private network for the media server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never done this, but there are programs out there that will allow you to do this.  [ForceBindIP](http://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/) is one of them.

Comment: thanks! this was exactly what i was looking for. works perfect!